# How to end session with parse-ruby-client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, parse-platform

hello im using the https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/tree/v0.3.0 gem and theres no documentation on how to end a session once logged in. So im curious on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gem does not support logout directly. You have to manually do the logout call like described on https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#sessions-deleting-sessions

Comment: is there some examples somewhere i can go from?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any method for `logout` in the [User](https://github.com/srikanthps/parse-ruby-client/blob/v0.3.0/lib/parse/user.rb) class of `parse-ruby-client` gem

If you wish, you can write a method like below, which will logout the current logged in user.

```
def logout
    Parse.client.post("https://api.parse.com/1/logout", {})
    rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError
        puts "Invalid session"
end
```

You can also choose to extend the classes provided by the gem by doing something like this in one of your ruby files

```
Parse::Protocol::LOGOUT_URI = "https://api.parse.com/1/logout"
module Parse
    class User
        def self.logout
            Parse.client.post(Parse::Protocol::LOGOUT_URI, {})
            rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError => e
               Parse.client.logger.error e.message
        end
    end
end
```

After that, you should be able to call a method like below:

```
Parse::User.logout
```

Comment: i implemented the `def logout..`  `and i hit localhost:3000/login/logout` and i get this back: `209: invalid session token`

Comment: this is my login_controller.rb https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f11a1dea8d21fee7b40c

Comment: with my login code, does a session automatically generated?

Comment: Unless login is sucessful, you cannot call logout.  Also, you have defined `logout` method inside `log_in`,  I think  you need to take it out and make it an independent method.  In your `log_in`, you don't need to call `logout` on exception

Comment: i have logout under `def logout`, its not under `log_in`

Comment: Look at my comment at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f11a1dea8d21fee7b40c   You have defined your `logout` inside `log_in`, not sure thats the right way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84881/discussion-between-user3670235-and-wand-maker).